# SQL Server exists not working in select statement

Tags: sql-server

Query 1 below returns the correct result. But why does query2 return a wrong result? It looks like the exists in query2 doesn't work as expected. Tested on SQL Server 2016.

```
create table #t1 (id nvarchar(20), typ nvarchar(20))

insert into #t1 
values ('1', 'stu'), ('2', 'exstu'), ('string', null)

create table #t2 (id int)

insert into #t2 
values (1), (3)

    --
    --select * from #t1
    --select * from #t2
    --drop table #t1
    --drop table #t2

-- Query #1:
select *
from #t1
where #t1.typ = 'stu' or typ = 'exstu'
  and exists (select * from #t2
              where #t1.id = #t2.id)

-- Query #2:
select *
from #t1
where exists (select * from #t2
              where #t1.id = #t2.id)
  and #t1.typ = 'stu' or typ = 'exstu'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want both queries to give the same result, you'll need to add parentheses to your second query's WHERE clause to have the boolean logic match up:

```
select *
    from #t1
    where
     exists (
        select * from #t2
        where #t1.id = #t2.id
    )
     and (#t1.typ = 'stu' or typ = 'exstu')
```

Answer (score 2):

AND takes precedence hence the last condition `typ = 'exstu'` in your second query causing and additional rows to be included in result set. Please check [operator-precedence-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql)